# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FirebaseUser'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Im working on a flutter auth app, while trying too sign out im getting an error , type null cant be assigned to the parameter type.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_app/app/home_page.dart';
import 'package:time_tracker_app/app/sign_in/sign_in_page.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  FirebaseUser? _user;

  void _updateUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    setState(() {
      _user = user;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_user == null) {
      return SignInPage(onSignIn: _updateUser);
    }
    return HomePage(
      //error
      onSignOut: () => _updateUser(null),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, I've tried changing the logic a little bit using the `user.uid` as a String instead of all the User class. I know that it is not the most sexy solution, but it works in the end.

```
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  String? _userId = '';

  void _updateUser(String userId) {
    print('User id: $userId');
    setState(() {
      _userId = userId;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_userId == '') {
      return SignInPage(
        onSignIn: (user) => _updateUser(user.uid),
      );
    } else {
      return HomePage(
        onSignOut: () => _updateUser(''),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` get the current user which has User(Firebase) return type and pass as an argument..

Sample code:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut;
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
onSignOut(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
```